# Outlook rule to mark all messages in folder as read

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, rules

We have an external system that sends emails if a build has failed, and another email if the build has been fixed. I use an email rule in Outlook 365 to move the emails from this system to a subfolder. When I've been away for a while and someone broke and then fixed the build, I find a bunch of unread "build broken" emails in this subfolder, and a "build fixed" email. Now, I want these emails to remain unread if they are copied while the build is still broken, but if someone fixed it, I can ignore all the "build broken!" emails (and the "build fixed" email can be ignored as well). Basically I only want to see unread emails in that folder if I look at outlook while the build is still broken.

I figured I could add a rule that marks everything in the folder as read as soon as I get a "build fixed" email, but rules only seem to apply to a single email, not a whole folder. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You need to create a VBA rule.

Comment: Agree with harry. Outlook doesn't have such a built-in option to realize this. You need to seek some VBA code or third-party tools